# Error while connecting to mysql server in shell script

Tags: mysql, database

Below is the script I'm running

```
mysql -h 192.168.1.100 -u $_dba_user -p$_db_password $_dba << eof
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS \`csv_temp_table\` (
\`id\` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
\`ProductType\` varchar(100),
\`Publisher\` varchar(100),  
\`Gerh\` varchar(100),  
\`Title\` varchar(100),
\`PlatformFormat\` varchar(100), 
\`Artist\` varchar(100), 
\`Genre\` varchar(100),
\`Theme\` varchar(100), 
  PRIMARY KEY (\`id\`)
);  
eof
done
```

When I try to connect,I get the following error

```
 ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'admin'@'192.168.1.20' to database 'test'
```

I'm trying to connect to the host **192.168.1.100** but it shows an error with **192.168.1.20** in it.
I'm using correct password,dbname etc..Please help me solve this issue.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Is user admin from system 192.168.1.20 allowed to connect to db test?

Comment: @cyrus what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: yes,but i need to connect to 192.168.1.100

Comment: *You* are the user on 192.168.1.20. It looks like it successfully logged you in, but you lack right to access the database named `test`.

Comment: yes I'm sure,I've tried the same with a wrong password also

Comment: you need to allow YOUR ip to remotely connect to the database, this is done on the db-server itself , when you are logged in with a permitted user

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'admin'@'192.168.1.20' to database 'test'

The error means that the user `admin` doesn't have permission to connect to database `test` from the IP address `192.168.1.20`.

Add permissions to your db, e.g.:

```
GRANT ALL ON *.* TO 'admin'@'%' identified by 'mypassword';
```

Note: this will give full access to all databases and tables to the admin user logging in from any IP address - you should probably limit the permissions somewhat.